# The URL request in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I remember , by default, any request to a URL that doesn’t match a URLpattern and doesn’t end with a slash will be redirected to the same URL with a trailing slash.But I occurred a problem.

the URLConf in my project :

```
#in urls.py file
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^cms/', include('cms.urls'))
)

#in the cms/ulrs.py
urlpatterns = patterns('cms.views',
    url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'category', name="cms-category"),
    url(r'^search/$', 'search', { 'template' : 'cms/story_list.html'}, name="cms- search"),
)
```

If I typed: 127.0.0.1:8080/cms/search/  worked.
But if I type 127.0.0.1:8080/cms/search , then 404 occurred.

I just wonder why this problem existed? Can anyone give me some tips? thank you !

Comment: you may need to check you [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) settings .

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to fix this would be to check the value of APPEND_SLASH in your settings.py file as suggested by John Wang. This will work only when CommonMiddleware is installed. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-APPEND_SLASH

Alternatively, you can add a question mark at the end of the URL Pattern in order to make the slash optional.

```
url(r'^search/?$', 'search', { 'template' : 'cms/story_list.html'}, name="cms- search"),
```

This way both '127.0.0.1:8080/cms/search/' and '127.0.0.1:8080/cms/search' will work.

It is helpful since even if we only link to one format we know people will probably visit both, either by entering the URL manually or by linking from an external source. But these are considered as two distinct URLs by search engines.

This can be tackled by doing something like the following in your URL Patterns:

```
url(r'^search$', redirect_to, {'url':'/search/'}),
url(r'^search/?$', 'search', { 'template' : 'cms/story_list.html'}, name="cms- search"),
```